# Serving web page with Docker using custom /etc/host on host machine

Tags: laravel, docker

I have added a host/ip to my macbook pro's `/etc/hosts` file. So something like:

`192.168.0.0 example.test`

What I would like to do is run a web server with Docker that utilizes the hostname, instead of 'localhost'

I can't figure out how to make this work. I have a laravel project running, and can make it serve to localhost with Docker via:

`php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0`

I have tried using the `--add-host` flag with Docker's run command when I start the container. So something like:

```
docker container run  -it -p 80:80 -v $(pwd)app  --add-host example.test:192.168.0.0 my-custom-container bash
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am pretty stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The `--hostname` argument provides the hostname of the container itself.

```
docker container run  --hostname example.test -it -p 80:80 -v $(pwd)app  --add-host example.test:192.168.0.0 my-custom-container bash
```

Example:

```
$ docker run -it debian
root@2843ba8b9de5:/# hostname
2843ba8b9de5
root@2843ba8b9de5:/# exit
$ docker run -it --hostname foo.example.com debian
root@foo:/# hostname
foo.example.com
root@foo:/#
```

Comment: Did I understand your question correctly? I added an example to show what `--hostname` is supposed to do.